# Efficient algorithm for index mapping

Tags: c++, algorithm

suppose you are given the following problem. You have two index sets that have a one-to-one mapping. For simplicity, let say, you have an array like `int a [] = {21, 30, 45, 78}` this list maps {1, 2, 3, 4} to {21, 30, 45, 78}. What is the most efficient way to obtain the reverse mapping, i.e. given index `30` you'd want the algorithm to return `2` for `45`, you'd want `3` and so on. I can think of the following:

1. A binary search for the index. This is memory efficient and has complexity `O(log n)`.
2. Have an array that has `79` elements and have `reverseMap[21] = 1, reverseMap[30] = 2, reverseMap[45] = 3, reverseMap[78] = 4`. This is `O(1)` and thus faster but is not memory efficient.

For my application both memory and speed are important. I'm short of memory since this is a number crunching code and thus will work with hundreds of millions of points. Speed is also important since the algorithm will be called many many times.

I sense Hash tables are useful here but I don't know much about it to comment. I'd appreciate any insight on the problem. Also, since the coding is done in `c++` I'd like to see methods that utilize `STL` and not external libraries.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit not really -- just a part in an ongoing project. I have a solution but what to know what other people think

Comment: Then I believe you're looking for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: What solution have you tried and why is it inadequate?

Comment: I know you requested internal libraries, but it is worth investigating the boost bimap. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html

Comment: So your array `a` is always sorted?

Comment: hashes are standard: `std::unordered_map`,  O(1)-ish, and much lower memory overhead.

Comment: So couple of things:

1- FloppyDisk: The solution involves using an object from a library that the code is built with and what it does is actually the mapping. Unfortunately i've been told that may not be very efficient and I'm not sure what it does internally.

2- TheBuzzSaw: Ahhh the boost! :D will look at it but already the code is dependent on other packages and I'd like to minimize that

3- MrE: Nope

Comment: @GradGuy: Write one comment per comment and, when doing so, use `@notify` syntax so that the users get told about your reply. Five months and eight questions is long enough to learn how SO works!

Comment: @GradGuy: if the vector is not sorted, you cannot use a binary search as a reverse lookup, you'd have to fall back on a linear search, or _also_ holding onto a sorted version.

Comment: @GradGuy: If your array needs fast lookup of "hundreds of millions of points", you are going to need to think differently, that data won't efficiently fit in memory.  If this is for a user-program, you probably need to redesign.

Comment: @MooingDuck: hummm I was under the impression that binary search would  work even on unsorted lists ... but now that I think about it, you are correct!

Comment: if you know something more about the distribution of the values you can do better than binary search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always: **PROFILE**.  We can guess, but without running your code, we might be wrong. I made a [rough benchmark on ideone](http://ideone.com/U0ufy) (times are based on my computer).  I did one hundred thousand lookups of `unsigned int` in an array with ten million elements (I got bored waiting for your "hundreds of millions"), and these were my results:

```
unsorted vector  found 1633382974 in 2140 ticks.
sorted vector  found 1633382974 in 62 ticks.
unordered_map  found 1633382974 in 16 ticks.
std::map  found 1633382974 in 172 ticks. //that's half the time of a blink
```

However I have to note, maintaining these in the memory of your program will have some overhead over the unsorted vector.  If we add the creation time to the timings of the hundred thousand lookups, we get:

```
unsorted vector  found 1633382974 in 2141 ticks.
sorted vector  found 1633382974 in 1797 ticks.
unordered_map  found 1633382974 in 16218 ticks.
std::map  found 1633382974 in 30749 ticks. //a full thirty seconds
```

So, as you can see, the timings depend *entirely on what you do in your code*.  Try different things, time them *with optimizations on*, and go with the fastest for your code.

Comment: I will. Thanks for the helpful discussion :)

Answer (score 0):

> What is the most efficient way to obtain the reverse mapping

Dual `std::map<value, value>`. or `std::unordered_map` I.e. any map class, dual.
I.e. first map maps values from arrayA to arrayB, and second one maps values from arrayB to arrayA. Or first map maps index to value and second maps value to index.

You can do same thing using `std::lower_bound` (binary search) and two `std::vector<std::pair<value, value> >`, but you'll need to ensure that all data is sorted. It'll use less memory than two `std::map`s, BUT you most likely will spend more time ensuring data is sorted.

> For my application both memory and speed are important

1. You forgot about development time. If your perfect solution requires 3 months of time to make, it is probably not worth it.
2. You need to tell how much memory you have, what kind of data you use, and how much data is expected.
3. There is always balance. Either "speed" or "memory". Or something in the middle.

> hundreds of millions of points

Switch to 64bit, buy extra memory. Or store sorted data on disk (allows binary search of partially loaded data) and forget about speed, or try to process it somehow using "read from stdin, immediately write to stdout" fashion. Please note that hardware is cheaper than development time. Without knowing type of your data it won't be possible to recommend anything else.